# useEffect optimize, but unable to re-render when the passed array has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx-react, use-effect

So I have a Loader component that fetches data from the server and decides where to push/redirect based on the response.

loader.tsx

```
export const Loader = observer(({ children }: CorrectlyTyped) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    api.fetch(globalStore).then((response) => {
      setLoaded(true);
      if (response.autheticated) {
        history.replace('/authenticated-page');
      } else {
        history.push('/unauth-page');
      }
    });
  }, [globalStore]);

  loader = (
    <AnimatedStuff/>
  );

  return (
    <>
      {loaded ? children : loader}
    </>
  );
});
```

app.tsx

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Loader>
      <Route path={SomePath1} component={SomeComponent1}/>
      <Route path={SomePath2} component={SomeComponent2}/>
      <Route path={SomePath3} component={SomeComponent3}/>
      // ...and so on
    <Loader/>
  <Switch/>
<Router/>
```

on initial state `globalStore` has properties that are null or undefined. However, once the response is received, those properties get filled with values. However, the effect doesn't get applied. (e.g. when a user logs in, user will get redirected to `/authenticated-page` even user clicks browser's back still gets redirected to `/authenticated-page`, same idea with logging out). Or perhaps, I'm putting the wrong value at the useEffect second array argument.

On hindsight making the `response` as a dependency array on useEffect is the way to go but that doesn't seem to work as `response` is used specifically inside `then`. help.

Comment: `useEffect` only does shallow comparison for the dependency array.

Comment: okay, so say `globalStore.user` doesn't get checked?

Comment: a component re-render only when the props or the state has changed and since `globalStore` is probably a global object that gets mutated the component does not re-render and that is why `useEffect` never runs

Comment: @AsafAviv I see, what do you suggest that I should on the dependency array? I was thinking of `response` but it's not within the scope.

Comment: the dependencies array is not the problem here, the problem is that `globalStore` is a  global object that gets mutated, move it to a component and keep the data in state then pass the data through `props` or if its global pass it through the `context`

Comment: @AsafAviv in fact, im not even sure if `globalStore` should be a dependency at all, but I think the response  is.

Answer (score -1):

In case globalStore is a an object  try initlize it like globalStore ={};